# how to install ffmpeg-PHP for newbies to linux?

Tags: php, linux, encode, ffmpeg-php

I'm trying to convert an `.avi` video file I have in my server folder to `.flv' format using ffmpeg-PHP. My attempt to "install" ffmpeg-PHP was to extract the contents of the "ffmpeg-php-0.6.0.tbz2" archive into a separate folder. The video conversion script I'm using references the directory location of the files extracted from "ffmpeg-php-0.6.0.tbz2"

this is the conversion script:

```
<?php

// Set our source file
$srcFile = "/videos/clip.avi";
$destFile = "/videos/clip.flv";
$ffmpegPath = "/install"; //where I extracted "ffmpeg-php-0.6.0.tbz2"

// Create our FFMPEG-PHP class
$ffmpegObj = new ffmpeg_movie($srcFile);

// Save our needed variables
$srcWidth = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameWidth());
$srcHeight = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameHeight());
$srcFPS = $ffmpegObj->getFrameRate();
$srcAB = intval($ffmpegObj->getAudioBitRate()/1000);
$srcAR = $ffmpegObj->getAudioSampleRate();

function makeMultipleTwo ($value)
{
    $sType = gettype($value/2);

    if($sType == "integer")
    {
    return $value;
    } else {
    return ($value-1);
    }
}

// Call our convert using exec()
exec($ffmpegPath . " -i " . $srcFile . " -ar " . $srcAR . " -ab " . $srcAB . " -f flv -s " . $srcWidth . "x" . $srcHeight . " " . $destFile);

?>
```

After running the conversion script, I get the output, "Fatal error: Class 'ffmpeg_movie' not found in [conversion script location]"

I've read instructions on the ffmpeg-PHP page but it doesn't make sense to me. How do I execute these lines of linux code to install ffmpeg-PHP?

```
tar -xjf ffmpeg-php-X.x.x.tbz2

cd ffmpeg-php-X.x.x/
phpize

./configure && make

sudo make install
```

I think I'm using a shared hosting service by Inmotion with linux installed.

Comment: Isn't this like super pointless? I mean you are using the cmdline tool anyway for conversion. Why would you need the PHP binding then? -- And no, you can't compile it on shared hosting just like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on shared hosting, you will need to have shell access to be able to build the php extension.  Since the hosting is shared, you will not be able to modify the php configuration (php.ini) to load the ffmpeg extension automatically.

If you have shell access and the ability to compile scripts (not always common on shared hosting), you will need to build the extension and place the .so file in your home directory somewhere, and use the [dl()](http://php.net/dl) function to load the library on demand in your scripts.

Some hosts may disable dl(), or your ability to compile scripts.  If you don't have shell access then you are out of luck and only the host can install this for you.

Comment: Assuming I have shell access, how do I build the extension?

Comment: The building of the extension are the directions starting with phpize.  You will need to set a prefix in `./configure` to build to your home directory, i.e. `./configure --prefix=/home/myuser/ffmpg` or something like that.  When you run `make install`, it will install the extension to your prefix directory.

Comment: I get the gist of it. but where and how exactly do I run the code? Do I make a php file and execute those lines using `exec()` ?

Comment: You would need to ssh into your account on the server and run those commands from your shell, provided you have shell access with your account.  You can use a client such as Putty, TeraTerm, or the ssh client that comes with linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this tutorial:

http://mysql-apache-php.com/ffmpeg-install.htm

Comment: er, my computer is running Vista and I don't know how to execute linux code anyways.